# Why is it not possible to have the same name of two StaticQuery elements on two different layouts for Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

For example, if I have two layouts and I want to use the same layout I need to name the StaticQuery different for each layout:

layoutA.js

```
const LayoutA = ({ children }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
```

layoutB.js

```
const LayoutB = ({ children }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
```

The above will cause the following error:

> error GraphQL Error There was an error while compiling your site's
>   GraphQL queries.   Error: RelayParser: Encountered duplicate
>   defintitions for one or more documents: each document must have a
>   unique name. Duplicated documents:
>   - SiteTitleQuery

In a way they are two different StaticQueries which for two different pages (layouts) and should be acceptable unless StaticQueries can be shared between pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@LekoArts gave a good work around. I want to answer this: Why is it not possible to have same query name in 2 different files?

Gatsby [extracts all graphql queries from your files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/query-extraction/) & executes them independently. If query name were omited by user, a name will be generated for that query; but if it does have a name, it'll be in the same space with all other queries.

A perk of this system is that you can export a fragment in any of your files & it'll be available for use in other queries. Plugins & packages also make use of this, such as `gatsby-image` with `GatsbyImageSharpFluid` & `GatsbyImageSharpFixed`.

Other than using `useStaticQuery` hook (only available with React ^16.8), duplicated queries can be also extracted into a smaller components with `StaticQuery` or turned into a [fragment](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/#fragments).

Answer (score 8):

I personally wouldn't really care about the name, in fact you can leave the name out completely and Gatsby will use some unique, random name by itself. If you choose to give it a name you have to give it two different names, no workaround for that.

However, you could use the Hooks version of StaticQuery: `useStaticQuery`

That way you'd have no repetition.

---

So in a new component you could write the following:

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

function useTitle() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return data.site.siteMetadata.title
}

export default useTitle
```

And use it in your layout:

```
import useTitle from './useTitle'

const LayoutA = ({ children }) => {
  const title = useTitle()

  return <div><h1>{title}</h1>{children}</div>
}
```